# Random BSOD. Every morning i turn on laptop. minidump added

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, bsod

Random BSOD. Every morning i turn on laptop i get BSOD like ntfs_file_system or irql_not_less_or_equal or memory management.

I just installed clean windows 8.1 and got same BSOD again, thought it memory, cpu or hdd corruption, checked all possible stress tests, mem86 shows no errors.

minidumps here - http://1drv.ms/1yO0n2d

Hope someone can point why bsod reoccur every morning.

Interesting thing when i get 2 or 3 bsod errors, laptop on 4-5 restart start normally and works without problem untill next morning or if i turn off laptop for some time for example more than 2 hours.

Comment: Random mini-dumps are not very helpful.  Post the information from the dump itself, and edit your question, to include the information from the dump.  You can use something like BlueScreenViewer to determine which drivers were loaded at the time of the crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

digi

All three related to memory corruption (probably a driver.  I would start by running driver verifier.  See [**this wiki**](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wiki/windows_other-system/driver-verifier-tracking-down-a-mis-behaving/f5cb4faf-556b-4b6d-95b3-c48669e4c983) for instructions.

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was bad ram, memtest displayed tons of errors when checked ram separately.